# solving trigonometric nonlinear equations using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, trigonometry, equation

I am trying to solve trigonometric equation but I am getting error could not solve 2490*x - 833*acos(6889*cos(x)/2401 - 4488/2401) . What am I doing wrong?

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
z1=19
z2=30
z3=17
z4=30
z5=17
z6=100
m1=2
m2=2
N=510
a=4*83**2
b=4*49**2
x = Symbol('x',real = True)
n1=Eq(3000*x-323*acos((9604-27556+27556*cos(x))/9604)+510*(2*3.14-x-acos((9604-27556+27556*cos(x))/9604))-N*2*3.14)
solve([n1],x)
x = degrees(x)
print("degree values : ",x)
```

Comment: Hi, read carefully the traceback Warning message: `Eq(expr) with a single argument with the right-hand side
defaulting to 0 is deprecated. Use Eq(expr, 0) instead.` (which is ok... just fix it) but you get also an error message `NotImplementedError: could not solve 2490*x - 833*acos(6889*cos(x)/2401 - 4488/2401)`. So, as the message say... there is no algorithm to solve it. By the way do you know if the problem admit a solution?

Comment: I have tried Eq(expr, 0) but got the same error.

Comment: I'm almost sure "transcendental" equations like this one have no closed-form solution, though you should be able to get a numerical solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: I should received numerical solution with Newton iterative method, but I am doing something wrong

Comment: Oh, I thought `sympy` only did symbolic calculations.

Comment: You should add your attempt to use the newton method. PS there is also a `is_transcendental` attribute in sympy:)

Comment: probably not the best sol but have a look to [link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html?highlight=newton%20method#using-the-nodes). For an abstract approach, if an algorithm lead to a sol or not [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html?highlight=newton%20method#module-sympy.codegen.algorithms)

Comment: I got wolframalpha.com to graph this and it has major discontinuities and sharp corners (ie, derivative not defined). Newton's method may fail. It appears x=0 is the only solution, but I didn't dig deep